# Camera preview with image effect like iphone

Tags: android

I want to implement camera view like apple development,which shows multiple image effects.and after selecting that effect we can take picture of that image effects.
  i had tried with image filters.but its not that way

Answer (score 0):

You should list all the effect available for your devices with:

```
 List<String> list=parameters.getSupportedColorEffects();
```

then if you want to set one (for example, the posterize one):

```
 if(list.contains("posterize")) {
    parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_POSTERIZE);
    myCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Comment: what do you mean exactly ?

Comment: total 3-5 effetcs displaying on same screen while camera start...and when we select one of it our camera will capture pic of that effects

Comment: you could use a RadioButton listing the fx you need, and call it from the activity: int selected_fx = mRadioFx.getCheckedRadioButtonId();